# What is associated data type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

In the routing section, the [article](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics) says:

> We can see that the RenderRoute class defines an *associated data type*
>   providing the routes for our application.

What does *associated data type* mean? It means type families?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting code from the article:

```
instance RenderRoute HelloWorld where
    data Route HelloWorld = HomeR
        deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
    renderRoute HomeR = ([], [])
```

As you can see `Route` is an associated data type and yes, it means data families. Take a look at [wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) example:

> We define a type class whose instances are the types that we can use as keys in our generic maps:
>
> ```
> class GMapKey k where  
>     data GMap k :: * -> *  
>     empty       :: GMap k v  
>     lookup      :: k -> GMap k v -> Maybe v  
>     insert      :: k -> v -> GMap k v -> GMap k v
> ```
>
> The interesting part is the associated data family declaration of the class. It gives a kind signature (here `* -> *`) for the associated data type `GMap k` - analogous to how methods receive a type signature in a class declaration.

Comment: I thought, that type families is defined with `type` instead of `data` like show in https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2014-12-12-type-families.html

Comment: it depends what you want: using existing type (type) or creating a new one (data)

Comment: Look at the https://www.yesodweb.com/book/haskell in the type families, there is a definition of `type Content a` and what is it?

Comment: @zero_coding The TypeFamilies extension includes both type families and data families.  They are very similar conceptually, with the difference between them being the same as the difference between (non-family) type aliases and (non-family) data types.

Comment: what are the differences between `type families` and `data families`?